# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses for python in osx

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, curses

I'm trying to install curses python lib on osx with:

```
pip install curses
```

But I'm'getting this error message:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for curses
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Curses is part of the standard library, it's not an external package.

Comment: Thanks! It is on a requirements file that I'm trying to use. I didn't know that.